# Cannot connect to remote PostgreSQL instance from Django app running within Docker container

Tags: python, django, postgresql

I am trying to connect a Django app running inside of a docker container to a PostgreSQL database running on another computer (lets say with an IP address of 192.168.1.22). Thus far in my experimentation, I always get the following error when attempting to connect to the PostgreSQL instance from a docker container (my code works fine outside of the docker container):

```
Is the server running on host "127.0.0.1" and accepting
 TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
```

I've made sure that I allow all inbound connections to the PostgreSQL database (by changing the config file for my PostgreSQL server as recommended [here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/83984/connect-to-postgresql-server-fatal-no-pg-hba-conf-entry-for-host).

Here is my settings code in my Django app for the database connection:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql',
        'NAME': 'xxxxx',
        'USER': 'xxxxxxx',
        'PASSWORD': 'xxxxxxxxxxx',
        'HOST': '192.168.1.22',
        'PORT': '5432',
    }
}
```

Here is my Dockerfile:

```
FROM python:3.6
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1

# Install dependencies
RUN mkdir /config
ADD /config/requirements.pip /config/
RUN pip install -r /config/requirements.pip

# Install source code
RUN mkdir /src
WORKDIR /src
COPY ./src/ /src/

ENV UWSGI_WSGI_FILE=/src/xxxxxxxxx/wsgi.py UWSGI_HTTP=:8000 UWSGI_MASTER=1 UWSGI_WORKERS=2 UWSGI_THREADS=8 UWSGI_UID=1000 UWSGI_GID=2000 UWSGI_LAZY_APPS=1 UWSGI_WSGI_ENV_BEHAVIOR=holy

RUN python /src/manage.py collectstatic --noinput

EXPOSE 8000

CMD ["uwsgi", "--http-auto-chunked", "--http-keepalive"]
```

Here is the script I use to build (& run) my docker container:

```
#!/bin/bash

docker build .

docker run -i -t -p 8000:8000 xxxx/xxxxxxx
```

I've also tried using the add-host option for Docker to add the database as a host, then reference the host name from within the settings file of my project. In all scenarios I end up with the same error above.

Thank you for the help in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I fix this problem using `extra_hosts` and `Docker-compose`

For example

```
web:
image: my-web-app
build: .
command: bash -c "uwsgi --http-auto-chunked --http-keepalive"
ports:
  - "8000:8000"
extra_hosts:
  - "postgresql:192.168.1.22"
```

In your Django configuration

```
DATABASES = {
'default': {
    'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql',
    'NAME': 'xxxxx',
    'USER': 'xxxxxxx',
    'PASSWORD': 'xxxxxxxxxxx',
    'HOST': 'postgresql',
    'PORT': '5432',
}
```

To run your app use `docker-compose up`